# Resize div height with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I'm trying to resize div heights dynamically based on browzersize, and based on this script (found     [here](http://demo.smartnetzone.com/same-height-columns-using-jquery/) ):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setHeight('.col');
});

var maxHeight = 0;
function setHeight(column) {
    //Get all the element with class = col
    column = $(column);
    //Loop all the column
    column.each(function() {       
        //Store the highest value
        if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();;
        }
    });
    //Set the height
    column.height(maxHeight);
}
```

script works great, I just need it to also run when a browser window is resized for responsive purposes.

It would make sense to do something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
setHeight('.col');
});
```

and then also reset the "maxHeight" somehow...

No bueno - any ideas?

Comment: By 'responsive purposes' do you mean when the user stops resizing the window?

Comment: you need to put the `var maxHeight = 0;` inside the function

Comment: I did, Pete. Posted the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/f99mD/1/ with "Imbecile'" suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KwhRv/)**

For thie first time that `setHeight` function runned, the `height` of elements initialized.
And for the second time, always the same height will be returned. You must remove the `height` from them
before your loop:

```
column.css('height', 'auto');
```

And, also your `var maxHeight = 0;` must be in your function itself:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setHeight('.col');
});


function setHeight(column) {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    //Get all the element with class = col
    column = $(column);
    column.css('height', 'auto');
    //Loop all the column
    column.each(function() {       
        //Store the highest value
        if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    //Set the height
    column.height(maxHeight);
}


$(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight('.col');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

edit:  here you go. it works for me :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setHeight('.col');

   /*if this is not placed before it is to be called, 
     the browser won't recognize it, 
     which is why i preferably register these 
     event functions in ready()*/
   window.onresize=function(){setHeight('.col');}; 
});

function setHeight(column) {
   var maxHeight = 0;   
   //Get all the element with class = col
   column = $(column);
   //Loop all the column
   column.each(function() {       
   //Store the highest value
     if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = $(this).height() ;
     }
  });
   //Set the height
   column.height(maxHeight);
   console.log(column +" " + maxHeight);
}
```

misread the q: make the maxHeight variable local to the function. It's value will then be reset whenever you exit the function.

Comment: how about: window.onresize=function(){setHeight('.col');}; if you are allowed to use JS as well

Comment: stil no... Posted my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/f99mD/ maybe i'm not doing it right...