# Resize 3 div's images as per screen size

Tags: javascript, css

I am very new to JQuery. I am trying to create a webpage which can be responsive as per the screen size it is viewed on. Usually I do it with CSS but this time I think will have to try JQuery.All div's will have images so need to give them height else they wont display.

The issue is when the page is loaded the left side main image div jumps like half the screen size and then resizes to the height that is generated by JQuery. For eg: the default height of the div is some 396 px and as per the screen it is given 798px so it sizes first to 396 and then to 798 and it shows and looks very bad.

The layout is such that there is no header but has a fixed footer and hamburger icon is in the footer which min-height 50px. I am using Bootstrap.

I have not used any css for main div's as I am using col-md-9 and col-md-3. I have also attached the layout below

The code is below

```
-- no header-- 
<div class="row">
  <div class="row" id="main-services">
       <div class="col-md-9" id="left-services"></div>
       <div class="col-md-3" id="right-services">
      <div class="row btn-menu top-right-services" id="top-right-services"></div>
          <div class="row bottom-right-services" id="bottom-right-services"></div>
       </div> 
  </div><!--class="row" id="main-services"-->
</div>

--fixed footer with min height 50px, the main menu is here--

JQUERY
script(document).ready(function($) {  

jQuery(window).on('load resize', function(){
                //get windows height
            var winWidth = jQuery(window).width();    
            var winHeight = jQuery(window).height();
            var imgHeight= winHeight-50;
            var onequater=(winHeight*1)/4 ;
            var threequater=((winHeight*3)/4)-50 ;

            jQuery('#left-services').css('height',imgHeight+'px');
            jQuery('#right-services').css('height',imgHeight+'px');
            jQuery('#top-right-services').css('height',onequater+'px');
            jQuery('.right-project-menu').css('height',onequater+'px');
            jQuery('#bottom-right-services').css('height',threequater+'px');
        });
    });
```

and I have also tried the code here [resize div - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837525/resize-div-height-with-jquery)

[layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9qzd.png)

Please help me

Comment: Using Javascript to solve this sounds like it's less than ideal unless you need to support old browsers.  Maybe checkout FlexBox - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Is the issue that you're trying to solve that it displays small first before the JQuery kicks in and modifies the height to the value you want?

Comment: Yes Stanley and because the footer is fixed at the bottom you can see it changing. Just now, i set #left-services to height 800px with some transitions in css so that it wont be that obvious when it changes to height by JQuery

Comment: BigJump, I will look into. but I am using bootstrap grid system anyways